# Unable to create-app in Grails 3.1.12 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: grails

I have installed `grails 3.1.12` on my Ubuntu desktop 16.04. When I give create-app command, Grails gives the following error:

```
Error Command [create-app] error: Replace: source file /home/keshava/.config/google-chrome/SingletonCookie doesn't exist (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

I have absolutely no idea why it is looking for google-chrome cookie, which incidentally exists as a symbolic link at that location:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 keshava keshava 20 Aug  7 18:17 .config/google-chrome/SingletonCookie -> 16987209158255805796
```

Any idea what is going on? I have googled and found no answers.

Comment: that doesn't look like a grails error message did you do `grails -version` first then `grails create-app myapp`  you haven't mentioned you did `grails create-app`. Or where you definitely in grails console

Comment: Grails (since version 3) has migrated their build tool to Gradle and the error message looks normally in that case.
Topic-starter, did you try to specify the "--stacktrace" flag as system suggested?

Comment: Just tried to do the same, and no errors. Grails was installed by sdkman.io

Comment: I installed using sdkman. I did: Grails and got Grails prompt.

Comment: I installed using sdkman. I did: Grails and got Grails prompt. Did "create-app hello" as I was trying to follow user documentation. That's when I got the error

Comment: Hmm, now I've tried to run command `create-app` from started grails and it doing something, but too long.
Ok, lets wait some time an watch.

Comment: I can approve that `create-app` from started grails now broken and do not working. Please use it in form `$ grails create-app hello`.

Answer (score 0):

I approve that `create-app` from started grails session now broken (versions 3.1.12 and even latest 3.2.0) and do not working.

Please use it in command line form `$ grails create-app hello`.
I've verified, that works.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will verify it on Monday and confirm. Meanwhile, is this behavior confined only to create-app? Or is the interactive mode itself is to be fixed in Grails 3.1.12? - Regards

Comment: Sorry don't know the answer, now I've checked only create-app. In addition I may say that command hates some special chars like '-' and '.' and maybe something else.

Comment: You're welcome.
Please accept that answer as correct.